# npm rollup.js ReferenceError: _default is not defined

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, module, rollupjs

Have spent hours trying to solve this, but have limited experience creating modules.

The error returned is:

```
ReferenceError: _default is not defined
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "esnext",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
    , "src/index.tsx"    
  ]
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import typescript from '@rollup-plugin-typescript';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';

export default {
  input: {
    Wordpress: 'src/Wordpress.tsx',
    ContactForm7: 'src/ContactForm7.tsx'
  },
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'cjs',
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.json'
    }),
    replace({
        'process.env.MY_VARIABLE': JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_VARIABLE)
    }),
  ],
  external: ['react'],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-wordpress",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "Test project",
  "main": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/test-project/nextjs-wordpress.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/test-project/nextjs-wordpress/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/test-project/nextjs-wordpress#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "rollup": "^3.10.1",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

./dist/index.d.ts

```
import { sendForm } from "./ContactForm7";
import { getPage } from "./Wordpress";
declare const _default: {
    getPage: typeof getPage;
    sendForm: typeof sendForm;
};
export default _default;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing your TypeScript code and ensuring that the `"_default"` variable or function is correctly defined and that it is in the correct scope when it is being used.

Comment: Its does appear to be set and is auto generated from the rollup build. I will add the file for reference